# Avoiding GLib memory pools & Valgrind possibly lost in C

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, glib

Due to [**memory pools**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254610/valgrind-reports-memory-possibly-lost-when-using-glib-data-types) `(g_slice)`, I get `possibly lost` in my code. My question is: is there anything I could do in my code to avoid leaking or is this purely a GLib issue?

All of these are reported as 'possibly lost'.

```
==2552== 
==2552== 744 bytes in 3 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 6 of 8
==2552==    at 0x40235BE: memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:694)
==2552==    by 0x402361B: posix_memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:835)
==2552==    by 0x408693E: ??? (in /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.1600.6)
==2552==    by 0x4088112: g_slice_alloc (in /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.1600.6)
==2552==    by 0x405B503: ??? (in /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.1600.6)
==2552==    by 0x804876C: add_inv (in /home/user/a.out)
==2552==    by 0x8048818: main (in /home/user/a.out)
```

---

```
#include <glib.h>
static GHashTable *hashtable1;
static GHashTable *hashtable2;

int add_inv (char *a, char *b) {
  GHashTable *table = NULL;
  gpointer old_value;
  char *mykey = NULL;
  int i, plus, *pointer;

  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
      if (i == 0)
        {
          table = hashtable1;
          mykey = a;
        }
      else if (i == 1)
        {
          table = hashtable2;
          mykey = b;
        }
      old_value = g_hash_table_lookup (table, mykey);
      if (old_value != NULL)
        {
          pointer = (int *) old_value;
          plus = *pointer + 10;
        }
      else
        plus = 10;

      pointer = g_malloc (sizeof (int));
      *pointer = plus;
      g_hash_table_replace (table, g_strdup (mykey), pointer);
    }
}

int main () {
  int i;
  hashtable1 = g_hash_table_new_full (g_str_hash, g_str_equal, (GDestroyNotify) g_free, g_free);
  hashtable2 = g_hash_table_new_full (g_str_hash, g_str_equal, (GDestroyNotify) g_free, g_free);

  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
      char *a = g_strdup ("val1");
      char *b = g_strdup ("val2");
      add_inv (a, b);
      g_free (a);
      g_free (b);
    }
  g_hash_table_destroy (hashtable1);
  g_hash_table_destroy (hashtable2);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set G_SLICE environment variable to reconfigure the GSlice memory allocator.

```
G_SLICE=always-malloc ./your_application
```

Here is the related part of the [GLib documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-running.html).

> This will cause all slices allocated through g_slice_alloc() and
>   released by g_slice_free1() to be actually allocated via direct calls
>   to g_malloc() and g_free(). This is most useful for memory checkers
>   and similar programs that use Bohem GC alike algorithms to produce
>   more accurate results. It can also be in conjunction with debugging
>   features of the system's malloc implementation such as glibc's
>   MALLOC_CHECK_=2 to debug erroneous slice allocation code, allthough
>   debug-blocks usually is a better suited debugging tool.

Comment: I got that part, however, I'm interested to see if I can somehow get rid of them within my code and not just when I execute the program.