# Properly deallocating a GtkBuilder Object

Tags: c, memory-leaks, gtk, valgrind, gtk2

I have the following GTK+ program

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Example can be compiled with:
// gcc gui.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
//
// GUI file from glade must be in same folder from
// which the compiled binary is called.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GtkBuilder *gtkBuilder = gtk_builder_new();

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    gtk_builder_add_from_file(gtkBuilder, "../gui.glade", NULL);

    gtk_builder_connect_signals(gtkBuilder, NULL);

    gtk_widget_show(GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(gtkBuilder, "main")));

    g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(gtkBuilder));

//  g_free(gtkBuilder);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

and the corresponding XML Glade file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="2.24"/>
  <!-- interface-naming-policy project-wide -->
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="main">
    <property name="width_request">400</property>
    <property name="height_request">300</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="default_width">690</property>
    <property name="default_height">500</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="gtk_main_quit" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

When I compile and run a memory check with Valgrind then it complains that the memory allocated for `GtkBuilder` is *possibly* lost. When I uncomment the `g_free()` instruction I get an error about an invalid call to `free()`.

I know that the GTK+ framework itself has some leaks, i.e., it does not deallocate resources which it needs throughout its entire lifetime. Is `GtkBuilder` one of those resources that will be "leaked" or is there a way to release it properly without Valgrind complaining about it?

Comment: You need `G_DEBUG=gc-friendly` and `G_SLICE=always-malloc` in order for valgrind to work correctly with `GObject`. [This answer also has some useful information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48911999/1983495).

Comment: Please please please, unless you really have a very good reason to do so (like maintaining a big and old application not worth migrating), don't use GTK+ 2. GTK+ 3 has been around for 7 years (!) and GTK+ 4 is likely to be released in 2019.

Comment: @liberforce I will probably migrate the program to GTK+ 3. The reason I started with GTK+2 is simply because Slackware shipped Glade with a version that works with GTK+2.

Comment: On distributions, glade is often packaged as `glade` or `glade3`, one version being for GTK+ 2, the other for GTK+ 3. What is tricky is that `glade3` is for GTK+ 2 (version <= 3.8) and `glade` for GTK+ 3 (version > 3.8) as shown on the [glade website](https://glade.gnome.org/sources.html). So you should be able to find [glade for slackware](https://slackbuilds.org/result/?search=glade&sv=).

Answer (score 2):

After "unreferencing",  and since you didn't increase the reference count, i.e, the reference count has dropped to 0, then the object its freed. Using `g_free()` afterwards will be an error.

From the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-unref):

> `g_object_unref ()`
>
> `void g_object_unref (gpointer object)`;
>
> Decreases the reference count of object . **When its reference count
>   drops to 0, the object is finalized (i.e. its memory is freed).**
>
> If the pointer to the `GObject` may be reused in future (for example, if
>   it is an instance variable of another object), it is recommended to
>   clear the pointer to `NULL` rather than retain a dangling pointer to a
>   potentially invalid `GObject` instance. Use `g_clear_object ()` for this.

Comment: This might be true but [valgrind will still report errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25342421/1983495).

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi maybe we should change tags to Valgrind instead of Gtk :/